# Reload a javascript widget based on a time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, refresh

`http://jsfiddle.net/4B2Bc/1/` <- the link to the widget

I have this javascript widget, which I want to reload every 60 seconds so the content on it is refreshed. However the problem is that whenever I use set timeout or anything else within the widget or outside the widget, the whole screen goes black when the widget refreshes.

In the debug window I can see that the json file for the new content is retrieved with the right content but it doesnt apply.

So the only other method I was left was to keep on writing the `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domainsoutlook.net/wjs/12_61532/" charset="utf-8"></script>` tag which reloads the whole js and refreshes the widget, but the problem with this is that it happens quickly and at once, not periodically.

Any solutions guys...I am willing to use jquery in the widget if it is going to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script erases the page because you're using [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write):

> Writing to a document that has already loaded without calling `document.open()` will automatically perform a `document.open` call.

And [`document.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.open):

> If a document exists in the target, this method clears it.

So if you call `document.write` any time except when the document is being initially loaded, you'll replace the entire document with what you write.

Don't use `document.write` to do your updates, just use a bit of AJAX to reload some new data from your server and then replace just the parts you need to replace using what ever DOM manipulation or jQuery techniques work best.

Once you have that working, use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) or [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) to arrange calls to your server for fresh data.

Comment: i dont use ajax for retrieving the data. I add another javascript that has a an array of data with a function that triggers that data array to be processed by the main js file. So the way I wanted to do that was to reload that function again and refresh the javascript call. Some way around the method that I am using

Comment: @Anush: Sounds like you're trying to hand-roll a JSONP system.

Comment: So what should I do to append to the document instead of rewriting it.

Comment: @Anush: You could use `document.createElement('script')` to build a new `<script>` element and then [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild)to add it to the page. Or use AJAX/JSONP to just load more data as needed.

Comment: I use an inputEx widget. Here the thing is that I reload the options using normal JS, but when I do `element.add` it adds to the dropdown, but the `choicesList` of the widget still retains the old list of values. So how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

using jquery you can set an interval, which is like a timer.

```
$(function() {
    setInterval( "refreshWidget()", timeinmilliseconds );
});
```

Comment: `setInterval` is not a jQuery function. Additionally, you should use the overload that takes a function reference instead of a string.